# C++ program in while (true) exits unexpectedly

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp, while-loop

I have two programs, a server (in C#) and client (C++). The server sends a command (cmd command) that the client executes. The client then sends the command's output back to the server. I've placed a comment that shows where the program stops in the code the below.

Client:

```
string cmd;
while (true) {
    cout << "Waiting for command" << endl;
    cmd = recvMsg();
    cout << "Got command" << endl;
    cout << cmd << endl;
    string cmdResult = exec(cmd.c_str());
    cout << "Executed command" << endl;
    //cout << "Got output from exec: " + cmdResult << endl;
    char sendBuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    strcpy(sendBuf, cmdResult.c_str());
    cout << "Converted into sendBuf\n";
    int result = send(s, sendBuf, strlen(sendBuf), 0);
    cout << "Sent command\n";
    // Program stops here, shouldn't it continue?
}
```

Server (Written in C#):

```
string cmdToSend = "";

if (cmdInput.Text != String.Empty)
{
    cmdToSend = cmdInput.Text;
    byte[] sendBuf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmdToSend);
    conn.Send(sendBuf);
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRecv = conn.Receive(recvBuf);
    string reply = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuf);
    Console.WriteLine("reply: " + reply);
    cmdOutput.Text = reply;

}
```

Note: cmdInput and cmdOuput are WPF textboxes

The exec command called in the client looks something like this:

```
string exec(const char* cmd) {
    FILE* fp = _popen(cmd, "r");
    string result;
    if (fp) {
        std::vector<char> buffer(4096);
        std::size_t n = fread(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(), fp);
        if (n && n < buffer.size()) {
            buffer.data()[n] = 0;
            std::cout << buffer.data() << '\n';
            result = buffer.data();
        }
        _pclose(fp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I run this, the client program ends after the command is executed and sent back to the server. Why does the program exit? It's in a while (true) loop and the server is still up so shouldn't it go back to the top of the loop? I'm pretty sure it has  something to do with the exec() command because when I remove it the program doesn't end, but instead goes back to the top of the loop like it is supposed to.
Thanks.

Comment: What command is executed? The `_popen` documentation has a note:
"If used in a Windows program, the `_popen` function returns an invalid file pointer that causes the program to stop responding indefinitely.  `_popen` works properly in a console application."

Comment: You're using `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` in one place, `4096` in one place, and `1024` in one place, which is far from robust.

Comment: Don't post code that " looks something like" your real code. Post your real code.

Comment: @lucas.exe simple os commands like ```dir``` and ```cd``` are executed.

Comment: @molbdnilo that wouldn't change anything? And what do you mean by "real code"?

Comment: @TheCohort If the result is longer than `DEFAULT_BUFLEN`, you're in deep trouble. But you don't need `sendBuf` at all – you can send `cmdResult.c_str()` directly.

Comment: @TheCohort With "real code" I mean that you should post the actual code, not code that is "something like" it.

Comment: @TheCohort use "rb" option in `_popen`  because `fread` is binary-read. You can also change `buffer` type to `char[4096]` (`char buffer[4096]`) (`buffer.data()` -> `buffer` and  `buffer.size()` -> `sizeof(buffer)`). And you should read `sizeof(buffer) - 1` bytes to keep 1 byte to put '\0'. Please try these changes and let me know if it works.

Comment: @lucas.exe worked like a charm. Client doesn't exit anymore. If you want to make your comment an answer I'd be happy to accept it :). Thanks!

Comment: @molbdnilo I'll be sure to post my real code next time. Also I changed my code so I'm consistently using 4096. Thanks!